# Google API Error when deploying app to play store

Tags: android, google-play, cicd, privacy-policy

In our CI/CD we deploy our app to an internal test track on the google play store.
The upload fails with the following error:

```
Google Api Error: Invalid request - The apk has permissions that require a privacy policy set for the app, e.g: android.permission.CAMERA.
```

As far as I know a policy is not needed on internal tracks.

I added a policy but it still shows this error.